# Replacing character in Edittext while typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a function that returns some String for letter 'A'  when user chooses option 1 and some different String when user chooses option 2:

```
private String changeText(int option){
if(option==1)
    return "Y";
if(option==2)
    return "Z";
}
```

I want to replace the the character in EdittextView when the user selects option 1 and types 'A', replace A with "Y" and same for option 2 with "Z" and this to be done in real-time.
So I came up with TextWatcher.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (s.length() == 0)
      return;

     s.replace(editText.getSelectionStart(),    
     editText.getSelectionStart()+1, changeText(option));                                                                                                                                                                   

}
```

and it's not working. My guess is that I am trying to replace the character with newer one before it is printed(not sure). I just want to replace the last typed character at any cursor position according to the option selected.

Comment: what is and how to obtain the value `option`  in the line `s.replace(editText.getSelectionStart(), editText.getSelectionStart()+1, changeText(option));`

Comment: It's either 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
```

in this method you can change symbol before in render. Get CharSequence s and change character at position (start, start+count)